# How sass works with webpack in angular4?

Tags: css, angular, webpack, sass

Can we refer **sass** file instead of **css** file directly in the **index.html**?

If it is possible, how does the **webpack** compile **sass** into **css** file? Also, which is the best way to bundle the sass file while building the application?

I am using the following versions:

***webpack(3.5.5), angular/cli(1.4.1) and angular4***

My folder structure is like this,

```
src
├--- assets
|    ├--- sass
|    |    ├--- common.scss
|    |    ├--- base.scss
|    |    ├--- coustom.scss
|    ├--- css
|         ├--- common.css
|         ├--- base.css
|         ├--- coustom.css
|
├--- index.html
├--- .angular-cli.json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all browser does not understand `scss` ot `less`. so you have to compile then and convert them to css while running in your browser.

As you are using angular cli there is a pretty sumple way to do that and no configuration required.

#### new cli project

so while generating you project you can pass a flag to tell cli to choose scss instead of css.

```
ng new projectname --style scss
```

#### existing project

If its an existing cli project you can edit `.angular-cli.json` file to change from css to scss.

first your style need to scss

```
  "styles": [
    "/asset/scss/common.scss",
    "/asset/scss/base.scss",
    "/asset/scss/custom.scss",
    "/asset/scss/common.css",
    "/asset/scss/base.css",
    "/asset/scss/custom.css",
    "styles.scss"
  ],
```

and the default style is scss

```
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss",
    "component": {}
  }
```

For external js libraries you you add a `script` block and add your scripts there. it will automatically added to your build.

```
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
  ],
```

Comment: once this setup is done you can add all your css and scss files in your cli configuration

Comment: As you said, if we specify the scss files in .angular/cli.json, do we need to refer the scss files again in my index.html file? Now, my LOC is like this `<link href="./assets/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  `

Comment: Can you also specify  which is the best way to bundle the sass file while building the application?

Comment: No, while build angular cli will take care of it. it will take all your scss and css file and make a web pack build and add links to your index file. you dont have to do it manually

Comment: this is the bast was i think. cli will do everything and you dont have to do anything. `ng build --prod` will do everything from prod

Comment: Are you saying, if we specify any css or scss file in .angular/cli.json, we dont have to specify it again in the index.html file? And it will bundle and minify these files automatically?

Comment: What about the JS files? The bundling is the same as css files?

Comment: Yes but for the js files you need to add them in the js block. I am adding that to my answer as well

Comment: And again we dont have to specify the js file any where right? All we need to do is just to add it in the script block in the angular/cli.json file and it will be in the bundled format after building?

Comment: that is correct. these javascript files will be added automatically.

Comment: is it answer your question. you can accept the answer so that others can ge thelp